# Why does `cat foo | sed 's/bar/qux/'` > foo` erases the contents of foo?

Tags: linux, sed

```
$ cd /tmp
$ echo bar > foo
$ cat foo
bar
$ cat foo | sed 's/bar/qux/'
qux
$ cat foo | sed 's/bar/qux/' > foo
$ cat foo
```

The last `cat foo` shows that the contents of the file have been erased. Why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make reading and writing the same file in the same pipeline always "fail"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409893/how-to-make-reading-and-writing-the-same-file-in-the-same-pipeline-always-fail) - especially Gilles's answer

Answer (score 2):

The I/O redirection `> foo` is handled by the shell before executing the command.  The shell opens the file `foo` for write, erasing previous contents and then, executes the command.  In your case, `cat foo | sed 's/bar/qux/'` works with an empty file `foo` and hence, it has no effect.